# Android studio ARM emulator won't start

Tags: android, android-emulator, arm64

I created an android API 29 AVD with arm64 arch and now every time I try to run it (on windows 10) it loads the little window, I get about 5 bars and then it stops responding. I restarted the PC just to make sure, didn't help.

I tried to find other emulators with arm64, but if they do have the support for it (like BlueStacks) they don't have android API 29, and I do need 29 or 30...

Does anyone know a solution for this?